# C# ComboBox set index when I have ID

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a class similar to:

```
class ComboboxValue
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }

  public ComboboxValue(int id, string name)
  {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

To get selected values from Combobox I use:

```
Combobox cb = new Combobox();
cb.Items.Add(new ComboboxValue(10, "Example value"));
ComboboxValue tmpComboboxValue = (ComboboxValue)cb.SelectedItem;
```

but how can I set the index of the ComboBox when I know previously stored ID? 
...For this example, ID: 10 (from the sql query)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first solution which involves keeping track of the items you populated in the ComboBox:

```
// Populate the ComboBox
var values = new ComboBoxValue[]
{
    new ComboBoxValue() { ID = 1, Name = "Test" },
    new ComboBoxValue() { ID = 2, Name = "Test 2" },
};

comboBox1.Items.AddRange(values);

...

// Set selected item based on an ID
int id = 1;
comboBox1.SelectedItem = values.Single(x => x.ID == id);
```

You could just write `cb.SelectedItem = item` if you are passing around instances to the class instead of just ids.

You could also utilize the `ValueMember` and `SelectedValue` properties of the ComboBox to do this a little nicer.  You have to first set the `DataSource` property of the ComboBox in order to do so.  You should be able to set the DataSource to a simple list.

```
var values = new ComboBoxValue[]
{
    new ComboBoxValue() { ID = 1, Name = "Test" },
    new ComboBoxValue() { ID = 2, Name = "Test 2" },
};

comboBox1.DataSource = values;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

comboBox1.SelectedValue = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not using a comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";